# Creating a single linked list

Tags: assembly, linked-list, mips, singly-linked-list

I am supposed to create a single linked list with MIPS then sort it etc. Here is a piece of my code:

```
   .data
STR_NEWLINE:    .asciiz     "\n"
STR_ENTER:      .asciiz     "enter an integer(0 to finish): "

     .text
main:
    sw      $zero,0($sp)                # list_head = 0
    move    $s0,$sp                 # list_end adress
main_loop:
    la      $a0,STR_ENTER           
    li      $v0,4
    syscall

    li      $v0,5                   
    syscall

    blez    $v0,bubble_loop         

    addi $sp, $sp, -8               

    sw      $v0,0($sp)              
    sw      $t0,4($sp)              
    move    $s0,$sp                 

    addi $t0, $t0, -8              
    j       main_loop
```

It works well, it gets inputs from the user, stores them on the memory, sorts and prints as well. But the problem (may be not) is i am not sure is it a real linked list because as I know linked list structure is like:

| data | pointerToAnywhere | ... | data | pointerToAnywhere |

But in my code it's like one after another always, so there is no point to have pointers if next input can't be stored in any empty place in memory.

To sum up, how should i improve my code to have $sp = (any empty place in the memory) instead of "addi $sp, $sp, -8"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After my research i found the solution, actually it's very very easy i just missed somehow.

```
li $v0, 9
li $a0,(number of bytes of storage desired)
syscall
```

as the result of syscall 9, $v0 gets the adress of block.